# Segfault in Struct Containing Dynamically Allocated Array

Tags: c, data-structures

Data structure `vehicle_array_t` sometimes segfaults when a new `vehicle_t` is added to it.

I've tried inserting and removing things in different orders, but it may be an edge case that I am unaware of how to replicate.

Definition of the struct `vehicle_array_t`:

```c
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int used;
    vehicle_t *vehicles;
} vehicle_array_t;
```

Code used for adding to the array:

```c
void add_vehicle(vehicle_array_t *array, vehicle_t vehicle)
{
    if (array->used == array->size)
    {
        array->size *= 2;
        array->vehicles = (vehicle_t*)realloc(array->vehicles, array->size * sizeof(vehicle_t));
    }

    array->vehicles[array->used] = vehicle;
    array->used++;
}
```

The code should resize the array appropriately when a new `vehicle_t` is added, but, strangely, it segfaults sometimes. I can't see any issue with the code just from looking at it.

Comment: How are the `vehicle_array_t` members initialized? Besides not checking if `realloc` fails (and if it does your overwrite your pointer -> memory leak), I don't see anything obviously wrong. Suggest an [MCVE]

Comment: @MFisherKDX If `realloc` fails it is not "just" a memory leak... it will segfault at the next line as `array` is NULL

Comment: @4386427 -- Yup. Nice catch.

Comment: The members of `vehicle_array_t` are initialized using a starting size for the `vehicles` member followed by `malloc` from this size, `used` is set to 0, and `size` is set to the given initial size.

Comment: How is the `vehicles` array initially allocated? `realloc` assumes the pointer was originally allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. It can't be on the stack.

Comment: The `vehicles` array is initially allocated using `malloc`.

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: If I need to post all of the very large codebase for it to be complete, should I just add all of it?

Comment: @MeaninglessCode No. You should remove as much code as you possibly can, testing constantly to ensure that the code can still replicate the error. It is quite likely that you will find the bug yourself by this process.

Comment: No. Click on the link I gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way the posted code can segfault and that is if `realloc` fails (and therefore returns NULL). You should not `realloc` directly into the data pointer - always use a temp variable.

Your code should be:

```
void add_vehicle(vehicle_array_t *array, vehicle_t vehicle)
{
    if (array->used == array->size)
    {
        array->size *= 2;
        vehicle_t *tmp = (vehicle_t*)realloc(array->vehicles, array->size * sizeof(vehicle_t));
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            //realloc error
            // add error handling here... or just exit
            exit(1);
        }
        array->vehicles = tmp;
    }

    array->vehicles[array->used] = vehicle;
    array->used++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any particular reason that realloc would fail? I'm fairly new to using C and I typically use C++, so using realloc is new to me.

Comment: @MeaninglessCode It would mean "no memory available" so it wasn't possible to reallocate your data.

Comment: Well, that's strange. I shouldn't be running out of memory. The code in question is being used in a multi-threaded program, but it should still have enough memory there as well. The maximum amount of `vehicle_t` stored in these arrays is only about 20.

Comment: @MeaninglessCode Well, in that case the error is in some code you didn't post... In any case you should rewrite the function as done in my answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I guess I'll go figure out what I messed up.

Comment: @MeaninglessCode When you use multi-threading I assume you protect any shared data using semaphores, right?

Comment: `realloc` may also segfault if the pointer passed to it was not originally allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`

Comment: @MFisherKDX true... however, op told us (in a comment) that the initial allocation uses `malloc` so it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, mutexes are being used when new vehicles are added to the arrays in question. The original pointer to `vehicles` is created using `malloc`.

Comment: @MeaninglessCode I guess you need to post all your code... BTW: If you only add like 20 vehicles it should be easy to put a lot of debug print into the function...

Comment: Should I edit my initial question? I'm not sure if my post will remain MVCE if I have to post all related code.

Comment: @MeaninglessCode You can edit this question and add relevant code

Comment: If there is insufficient code to reproduce the problem, then _it is currently not an MCVE_. Rewriting the question to provide that information is done by _making it an MCVE_. Just dumping in "all related code" is not an MCVE. Long and short is you will need to debug this.

Comment: After debugging, I have realized that the issue stems from the `array->size *= 2` line. I have another function that removes from the array, so the size of the array can possibly be 0. Then, when `realloc` is called, it is asked to allocate 0 bytes and throws an error.

Comment: Hurray for debugging!